# Spring JPA Transaction Manager does not rollback

Tags: spring, jpa

I recently moved from Hibernate to JPA. Now I notice two things in my code.

1. Methods in my services do not need `@Transactional` anymore to perform insertion to the database.
2. Transaction never get rolled back even if there's any exception.

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa-1.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.service, com.myapp.batch,com.myapp.auth" />
    <!-- Configure the data source bean -->
    <bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">  
      <property name="dataSourceProperties" >
        <props>
            <prop key="url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/app?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull</prop>
            <prop key="user">user</prop>
            <prop key="password">pass</prop>
        </props>
      </property> 
      <property name="dataSourceClassName"   
                value="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" />  
    </bean>  

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource">  
          <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />  
    </bean>
    <!-- Create default configuration for Hibernate -->
    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
    <!-- Configure the entity manager factory bean -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myapp.persist" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">100</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer"
        depends-on="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="databasePopulator">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator">
                <property name="scripts" value="classpath:initial_data.sql" />
                <property name="continueOnError" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.myapp.repositories"
        entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    <!-- Enable annotation driven transaction management -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <task:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

**NetworkService.java**

```
@Service
public class AdminUserManagementService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    RequestRegisterHistoryRepository requestRegisterHistoryRepository;

    @Autowired

    @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
    public User saveUser(UserBO userBO){
        RequestRegisterHistory requestRegisterHistory = new RequestRegisterHistory();
        User user = new User();
        // ..
        requestRegisterHistoryRepository.save(requestRegisterHistory);
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }       
}
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="sec://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myapp.controller" />

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/webjars/**" location="classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->


    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        <beans:property name="order" value="1" />
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="contentNegotiationManager"
             class="org.springframework.web.accept.ContentNegotiationManagerFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="favorPathExtension" value="false" />
    <beans:property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="parameterName" value="mediaType" />
    <beans:property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true"/>
    <beans:property name="useJaf" value="false"/>
    <beans:property name="defaultContentType" value="application/json" />

    <beans:property name="mediaTypes">
        <beans:map>
            <beans:entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <beans:entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
       </beans:map>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean class="com.myapp.component.AppInterceptor" />
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ByteArrayHttpMessageConverter">
            <beans:property name="supportedMediaTypes" value="image/jpeg" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">

         <!-- setting maximum upload size -->
        <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="99999999999" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

I am using `Spring Version : 4.1.4` and `MySQL Table : MyISAM`

**Stacktrace**

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [null]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:248)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:214)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:417)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodIntercceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy37.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.myapp.service.AdminUserManagementService.saveUser(AdminUserManagementService.java:460)
    at com.myapp.service.AdminUserManagementService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f21244b7.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
```

How do I configure so I would require `@Transactional` annotation and any transaction get rolled back during exceptions ?

Comment: Read http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.7.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#transactions. Spring-data-jpa repositories are transactional. If you want the transaction to span a service method call, just make that service method transactional.

Comment: When I add that it still wont roll back. Any idea why ?

Comment: You are using MySQL do you have a transactional table type? You are using component-scanning do you also have a `DispatcherServlet` with the same component-scan? Also which spring version are you using and does your service implement an interface or is it a plain class?

Comment: you mention that there is a constraint violation but object is getting saved. which object. what constraint violation. can you give more  details. From where are you calling saveUser() as Spring proxies classes by default. So if you call this method from within the same class Transactional annotation will not work whereas if you call this method from another class transactional annotation will work. 

Can you elaborate "hit constraint violation however the object is still saved"?

Comment: @Deinum, the table used is MyISAM. The `DispatcherServlet` only exist in the web.xml. Spring Version is 4.1.4. My service is a plain class.

Comment: @premkumar, The service is called by a method in a controller. What i meant by the error message was, when `userRepository` fails to save an object due to a column must not be null, the previous save by `requestRegisterHistoryRepository` didn't get rolled back.

Comment: Can you put a debug point within saveUser() method. And while debugging check in the stack trace whether TransactionInterceptor is present or not. Can you check and report this.

Comment: @premkumar, yes the TransactionInterceptor is  present. Ill update the question with stacktrace.

Comment: In the code snippet it is NetworkService whereas in the stack trace it is AdminUserManagementService. Can you recheck and add in if you have missed out something in the problem statement

Comment: AdminUserManagementService is the same with NetworkService. I simplified the class name and the method implementation.

Comment: I think the problem is due to the table is using MyISAM ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with table engine that's `MyISAM`. The transaction is able to rollback after I changed the engine to `InnoDB`.

Setting the `hibernate.dialect` to `org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect` ensure the creation of table with `InnoDB`in the future.